Question Regarding the Existence of a Laurent Series
I'm currently quite stuck with this problem regarding the Laurent series of a function:

Determine whether or not the following function has a Laurent series at $z=0$,
and if it does, find its principle part. Also, specify if the function is singular at $z=0$, and if it is, state the type of singularity.

The function in question is $\frac{z+4}{z(z+2)}$.
I can isolate the singular point and rewrite the function as $\frac{\frac{z+4}{z+2}}{z}$, and then doing a Taylor series expansion of $\frac{z+4}{z+2}$ about $z=0$ gives me that the principle part of the Laurent series for this function is $\frac{2}{z}$. Furthermore, this function has a 1st order pole at $z=0$.
My question is, before doing any of this work, how do I address this part of the question?

Determine whether or not the following function has a Laurent series at $z=0$


You can probably deal with it directly by finding the laurent series

By directly computing you get for $0 \neq |z| < 2$
$\begin{align*}
\frac{z+4}{z(z+2)} &= \frac{1}{z} + \frac{2}{z(z+2)} = \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z+2} = \frac{2}{z} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{2}}\\
&= \frac{2}{z} - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geqslant 0} (-1)^{n} \frac{z^n}{2^n}\\
& = \frac{2}{z} + \sum_{n\geqslant 0} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}
\end{align*}$
Here t is direct, but if you already identified the principle part, just substract it and deal with the rest.
Also you can ask wolfram to check your answers: Laurent series of $\frac{z+4}{z(z+2)}$ at $z=0$.
I suggest you try this exercise at $z=-2$.
